# Install a packet with pip, ImportError

Tags: python, installation, pip

When I install a packet with pip (for example patsy)

```
[sudo] pip install patsy

Downloading/unpacking patsy
Downloading patsy-0.1.0.tar.gz (258kB): 258kB downloaded
Running setup.py egg_info for package patsy

no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/_build'
Requirement already up-to-date: numpy in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from patsy)
Installing collected packages: patsy
Running setup.py install for patsy

no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/_build'
Successfully installed patsy
Cleaning up...
```

And pip install in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packet/ and not in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packet/ and when i try to import a packet in Ipython I have this error:

```
import patsy

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-9de22d189b17> in <module>()
----> 1 import patsy

ImportError: No module named patsy
```

I have Linux Mint Mate 15. what's I do bad??

Comment: What platform are you on? Do you have multiple Python installations? My guess is that you're on Mac, and you've installed a second Python 2.7, and you're running a `pip` from one Python installation and then `ipython` from the other.

Comment: No error at the moment to install? Did you give the correct permissions to install `sudo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifying your PYTHONPATH, I recommend reading the following http://www.stereoplex.com/blog/understanding-imports-and-pythonpath

Comment: Thanks. I do: export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ and run. But this path is a temporary. To do for ever, you need edit the .bashrc archive